# Same CCK field in one content type

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type named "school;" this content type has the "teacher" CCK field, but the number of teachers is not same for any school.
I need a thing like "add new teacher" button, which can be used to a new "teacher" CCK field.
Does anyone know a module to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the number of allowed teachers to "Unlimited".

Answer (score 3):

School needs to have a nodereference field pointing to teacher. Then, as tim.plunkett [said](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/same-cck-field-in-one-content-type/2407#2407), you need to make the number of teachers node reference field to unlimited.
Same as the one detailed [here](http://pras.net.np/blogs/guide-cck-nodereference), but the number of values set to unlimited.